# How acess and modify SearchQuerySet(HayStack)?

Tags: python, django

I having some issues with haystacks. when i nitialize with my model that giving me a list with type SearchQuerySet:

```
def sqs_query(self, sqs):
    q = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('q', '')
    results = sqs.filter(content=q)
    pdb.set_trace() 
    sorted = sort(results)
    return sorted

def get_queryset(self):
    sqs = self.sqs_query(self.sqs_models(SearchQuerySet()))
    return sqs
```

`(pdb) type(results)`

`<class 'haystack.query.SearchQuerySet'>`

I can acess the position 0:

`(pdb) results[0]`

`<SearchResult: article.article (pk=u'5')>`

But i can't assign:

`(pdb) results[0] = results[1]`

`*** TypeError: 'SearchQuerySet' object does not support item assignment`

I need to modify the positions of the list to order the list. `order_by()` will no help me but i need to calculate my own values to compare. Every result has a `title` word. I will calculate Levenshtein_distance using the string `q` and every result will asscociate with a diferente value.

Comment: Why/ how do you want to modify the order? You probably want to use `order_by` on the queryset. If you're insistent on manually reordering things, you can convert it to a `list()` and do it there.

Comment: I want order by my way, but the `get_queryset()` needs to return a `SearchQuerySet` type not a `list()`

Comment: You should look into changing your model so there is a field or something that will allow you to sort using the database. Having python reorder a queryset on every request is generally very inefficient. Though, sometimes you can't get around it, and need to sort with python.